# Multiple local connections in flash - what's the better architecture?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, localconnection

I'm using localConnection in AS3 to allow several flash applications to interact with a central application. (Some are AS2, some AS3).

The central application must use a seperate localConnection variable for each receiving connection (otherwise the second app that tries to connect will be rejected).

But what about sending messages back?

Is it better to have the main application use a single localConnection to send messages to all the other applications, or should I assign a LC variable per target? (Since I specify the target anyway in the .send command)

1 Door for all of the messages to exit or 1 door per message target? Which is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem more organised to communicate with each Flash application separately, although I think it will work either way.